# Паттерн для создания однотипных объектов с различным количеством свойств

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, инспекция-кода, полиморфизм

### Дублирующий код

Есть вот такой код:

```
public class UserBaseInfo
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }           
}

public class UserFullInfo : UserBaseInfo
{
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public class UserBaseInfoCreator
{
    public UserBaseInfo Create(User entity) //User - database object
    {
        var userBaseInfo = new UserBaseInfo
        {
            Surname = entity.Surname,
            Name = entity.Name
        };

        return userBaseInfo;
    }
}

public class UserFullInfoCreator
{
    public UserFullInfo Create(User entity)
    {
        var userFullInfo = new UserFullInfo
        {
            Surname = entity.Surname,
            Name = entity.Name,

            SecondName = entity.Surname,
            Age = entity.Age,
            Email = entity.Email,
            Phone = entity.Phone
        };

        return userFullInfo;
    }
}
```

Когда необходимо получить полную информацию о пользователе, то в методе `UserFullInfoCreator.Create()` код инициализации свойств `Surname` и `Name` приходится продублировать *(в реальном проекте таких свойств больше и про AutoMapper я в курсе, не предлагать:), т.к. в реалии наименования свойств сущности и модели не совсем/не все одинаковы)*.

---

### «Фабричный метод»

Я реализовал паттерн «Фабричный метод» в целях избавиться от дублирования и вот что у меня получилось:

```
public abstract class UserInfo
{
    public abstract string Surname { get; set; }
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserBaseInfo : UserInfo
{        
    public override string Surname { get; set; } 
    public override string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserFullInfo : UserInfo
{
    public override string Surname { get; set; }
    public override string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public abstract class UserInfoMaker
{
    abstract public UserInfo Create(User entity);
}

public class UserBaseInfoMaker : UserInfoMaker
{
    public override UserInfo Create(User entity)
    {
        var userBaseInfo = new UserBaseInfo
        {
            Surname = entity.Surname,
            Name = entity.Name
        };
        return userBaseInfo;
    }
}

public class UserFullInfoMaker : UserInfoMaker
{
    public override UserInfo Create(User entity)
    {
        var userFullInfo = new UserFullInfo
        {
            Surname = entity.Surname,
            Name = entity.Name,

            SecondName = entity.Surname,
            Age = entity.Age,
            Email = entity.Email,
            Phone = entity.Phone
        };

        return userFullInfo;
    }
}
```

От дублирования как видите избавиться мне не удалось. Но мне кажется, что какое-то **одно** из трех утверждений верно:

1. Я неправильно реализовал паттерн «Фабричный метод».
2. Мне необходим другой паттерн.
3. Здесь не надо пытаться избавиться от дублирования, все и так хорошо,
   т.к. в любом случае данная реализация позволит в клиентском коде
   использовать не специфические классы, а манипулировать абстрактными
   объектами (полиморфизм).

---

### Вопрос

Я где-нибудь прав, или?

---

### Обновление

Сделал обновление, согласно данному ответу и комментариям:

```
public abstract class UserInfo
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public UserInfo(User entity)
    {
        Surname = entity.Surname;
        Name = entity.Name;

        Fill(entity);
    }

    protected abstract void Fill(User entity);
}

public class UserBaseInfo : UserInfo
{
    public UserBaseInfo(User entity) : base(entity) { }

    protected override void Fill(User entity) { }
}


public class UserFullInfo : UserInfo
{
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public UserFullInfo(User entity) : base(entity) { }

    protected override void Fill(User entity)
    {
        SecondName = entity.Surname;
        Age = entity.Age;
        Email = entity.Email;
        Phone = entity.Phone;
    }
}
```

**Этот вариант лучше?**

Comment: А почему бы не разделить `Create` на невиртуальный `Construct` и виртуальный `Fill`?

Comment: @VladD если бы ты пример показал, а то приходится догадываться: имеется ввиду в абстрактном классе `UserInfoMaker` будут эти два метода? Один из которых `(Constructor)` по умолчанию заполнит `Surname` и `Name`, а второй `(Fill)` будет запускаться конкретными фабриками по необходимости. Я как-то так это понял.

Comment: @VladD , вопрос обновлен.

Comment: ага, я имел в виду это, но присвоение Name/Surname я бы тоже вынес в UserBaseInfo.Fill (а в перекрытом методе вызывал бы базовый).

Comment: @VladD, может, тогда нужна фабрика, а не конструктор? Вызов переопределяемого метода в конструкторе базового класса не самая лучшая идея, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @Vlad: Хорошая идея, почему бы и нет?

Comment: @VladD, если в конструкторе будет инициализироваться то, что должно заполняться в методе Fill, то можно наступить на грабли. Не очевидно же, что метод отработает до конструктора.

Comment: @Vlad: Я понимаю, я имел в виду, что _ваша_ идея хорошая.

Comment: @VladD А. Неправильно вас понял :)

Comment: Как вы собираетесь использовать свой UserFullInfo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> в реалии наименования свойств сущности и модели не совсем/не все
>   одинаковы

Думаю не стоит в реалиях разделять сущность и модель. Вы потом запутаетесь в представлениях данных. Представьте тысячи классов - как потом программистам, кроме вас, помещать это всё в голову? По той же причине в принципе - разделение на `UserBaseInfo` и `UserFullInfo` выглядит странно. Чем меньше плодится классов - тем легче читается затем код (мнение).

> Мне необходим другой паттерн.

ActiveRecord - тут является подходящим паттерном. Тем более в .net фреймворке есть отличные богатые его реализации. Со стороны кода у вас всё верно - только это бы имело смысл, если бы один создатель конструировал сущности пользователей, а второй - сущности сообщений, например. Иначе абсурд.

Даже если решите оставить разделение UserBaseInfo/UserFullInfo - то вам подойдёт наследование + шаблонный метод + я бы вовсе убрал Creator-ы (почему не просто конструкторы??)

Comment: _Думаю не стоит в реалиях разделять сущность и модель_. Да, но Вы наверное согласитесь, что `доменный объект`, которым будет оперировать приложение, полностью совпадает с `объектом БД` когда приложение и БД проектируются изначально вместе. А дальше, когда другое приложение собирается использовать эту БД, то не редко приходится строить `доменный объект` из нескольких `объектов БД`.

Comment: @adamshakhabov , а как-же миграции? Гораздо проще привести БД к новому формату, нежели делать кашу из классов. Если же встаёт вопрос - использовать одну БД на несколько проектов: например БД где пользователи, как единую базу пользователей - выделяют третий проект(сервис), к которому два других обращаются, как API. Или же если ни выделять проекты, ни реструктуризировать БД - лень (например данные не ключевые) то скорее тогда подойдёт шаблон адаптер. То есть преобразовать что угодно к формату, которого требует проект.

Comment: вопрос обновлен.

Answer (score 0):

Паттерны
декоратор `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern`
или 
компонентная модель `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern`
могут вам подойти.

Answer (score -1):

неправильно реализован паттерн «Фабричный метод»:

1. паттерн «Фабричный метод» работает с интерфейсами, но абстрактными классами (отказаться от абстрактных классов и использовать интерфейсы)
2. паттерн «Фабричный метод» должен создавать неизменяемые объекты (отказаться от изменяемых объектов и использовать конструкторы и геттеры)
3. паттерн «Фабричный метод» работает лучше с «абстрактной» фабрикой - интерфейсом и реализациями

необходим другой паттерн:

1. паттерн «Фабричный метод» работает когда клиенты не должны приводить результаты к конкретным реализациям. Как клиент получит поле *Email* от чего-то, созданного UserFullInfoMaker или UserFullInfoCreator?

Этот последний вариант не лучше, легче продублировать код инициализации свойств Surname и Name: дольше писать, но легче читать и поддерживать.